# Why doesn't this set comprehension work?

Tags: python

In Python 2.6.5, given this list
    mylist = [20, 30, 25, 20]

Why does this set comprehension not work?

```
>>> {x for x in mylist if mylist.count(x) >= 2}
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    {x for x in mylist if mylist.count(x) >= 2}
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you.

Comment: Works for me with v2.7.2, I get `set([20])`

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features

Comment: Works for me in 3.2 also, though I'd note that `{x for x, count in collections.Counter(mylist).items() if count >= 2}` is O(n) instead of your O(n^2) approach.

Comment: Aha .. I can **reproduce** that error with **v2.6.5** under Linux, so I bet you are using pre-v2.7. (My error message includes another line about `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`)

Comment: @Levon So, clearly I have to upgrade one of my older machines to post 2.6.5. Thanks.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Looks that way. Under Win 7 I have 2.7.2 and 3.2.3, but my Ubuntu distribution comes stock with 2.6.5 and I too haven't upgraded that, though I probably should.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
$ python2.6
>>> mylist = [20, 30, 25, 20]
>>> {x for x in mylist if mylist.count(x) >= 2}
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    {x for x in mylist if mylist.count(x) >= 2}
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

$ python2.7
>>> mylist = [20, 30, 25, 20]
>>> {x for x in mylist if mylist.count(x) >= 2}
set([20])
```

You can accomplish the results in python2.6 using an explicit `set`, and a `generator`:

```
>>> set(x for x in mylist if mylist.count(x) >= 2)
set([20])
```

Comment: Also new in 2.7: The set literal (`{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} == set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`)

Answer (score 8):

What version of Python are you using? Set comprehensions [appeared in 2.7.x+ and 3.x+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Set_comprehension). If you're using an older version, you'll get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`:

```
>>> {x for x in mylist if mylist.count(x) >= 2}
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    {x for x in mylist if mylist.count(x) >= 2}
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

That is not the case with Python 2.7.x+ / 3.x+ :

```
>>> {x for x in mylist if mylist.count(x) >= 2}
set([20])
```